# jQuery error, Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function

Tags: jquery, function, object

i get the follow error :*"Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function "*
I check google and stackoverflow for answer but mainly is recommended to check if the query is included, so at my case it is.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#fakturayes").click(function () {
      $("#ffields").show("slow");
    });
    $("#faktura").click(function () {
      $("#ffields").hide("slow");
    });
</script>
```

Any ideas ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: jQuery doesn't exist on your page, or was overriden. That's the only way to have `$` undefined on `window`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible problems:

1. You have not importet JQuery **before your script** on this page
2. You have imported another js library that overwrites your JQuerys `$`

In case 1, just import it, in case 2, you can replace the `$` you want to be JQuery `$` with `jQuery`, and maybe use noConflicts, see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Thank you very much ! This slove my problem and i am sure it will come to hand in future. Thank you very much 5 stars !

Answer (score 1):

JQuery lbrary must be missing in your page